# what do i need to do to make my c++ program run by only entering the name on my unix system

Tags: c++, shell, compiler-construction, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code won’t run. [not]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570371/code-wont-run-not)

I have written and compiled a program and i want to make it so that from shell i can just type programname to make it run instead of going to the directory the the program is in  and typing ./ before the program name. If this is possible please let me know.

Comment: @Noah, your question is only a duplicate to the extent that people were able to read your mind and answer the question you didn't actually ask. I've voted to close it as not a real question for that reason. This question is clear and succinct, and actually asks the question in a way that makes the users's intent clear.

Comment: If I could, I would vote to retract one of the votes to close.

Comment: this question still needs 3 vote(s) from star wars fans to reopen

Comment: So this is going to happen to all of OP's questions?? Also, this belongs on SuperUser.com. Am I supposed to vote to reopen and then vote to close again? One user did that on Noah's nonsense question…

Comment: @Potatoswatter, If this really belonged on SU, then the votes to close should have been for migration to there. Personally, I think that this is programming related, it's just more about how to play nice with the rest of your system and its users than about how to code some specific algorithm. Regardless, the other question was so poorly worded that it got closed for not a real question so it isn't really fair to redirect people to it. Upvote the non-silly answers to this one, too, if that helps.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Cut the chatter, Red 2.

Comment: @anthony 1) This is not funny 2) "bring teh funnay" is not a valid reason to flag a post 3) did I mention this is not funny?  If not, let me do so now.

Comment: I voted to close as a joke.  I seriously didn't expect a bunch of people to follow suit.  There was no reason to close this question.

Comment: 8/26/2010: the day stackoverflow.com turned into everything2.com

Comment: For the record, I voted to migrate to superuser, not to close as off topic. Diamond Moderator powers kick question in rear.

Answer (score 16):

You must learn the ways of the [PATH](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cs348/unix_path.html) if you're to come with me to Alderaan.

Comment: That should've been:  "Yoder, you must learn the ways of the PATH". :)

Comment: Never his mind on what directory he was in. Hmm? What process he is running. Hmph.

Comment: Mudhole? Slimy? My $HOME this is!

Comment: I have altered the PATH. Pray I do not alter it further.

Comment: moving on to jedi now: Strong am I with the PATH, but not that strong.

Comment: too easy: Once you start down the dark PATH, forever will it dominate your destiny

Comment: Nominated for Comment Thread of the Year!

Answer (score 5):

You should [add the directory](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm) where your compiled program is to your PATH.

For example if you are inside the  `/home/jimmy/cpp` directory

type (leading $ is the prompt)

```
PATH=$PATH:`pwd`
$myprog
```

Read about [export](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html)ing variables and the [bashrc file](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-bashrc-file) to make this change permanent. (assuming bash as your shell)

Comment: Adding '.' to your path is an extremely, extremely bad idea.

Comment: Much more likely you should copy the program to $HOME/bin and ensure $HOME/bin is on your PATH.

Comment: @Anthony: I'm not a shell guy.. why exactly is that a bad idea?

Comment: @Billy ONeal: echo "rm -rf /" > ls. or, more generally, because typing a command will do different (unknown, possibly bad) things depending on $PWD.

Comment: @Billy: another way of explaining - if you type something it searches your path in order. If . is early in the path, then someone who anticipates that can put a bogus command with the same name in a directory you might cd into and that they can write to (e.g. /tmp), allowing them to do arbitrary things under your user id. Similarly, they may anticipate possible typos, like 'sl' for 'ls', which would give them control even if '.' is the last directory searched. The command's output can look as if the real command ran, or 'sl not found'/exit(1) as appropriate.

Comment: @Billy:  See my detailed answer in this question.

Answer (score 4):

**A detailed discussion of why putting `.` (current directory) in the `PATH` is a bad idea.**

Lets say you're being attacked by an adversary on your machine.
He authors a malicious program, and puts it in a directory, hoping that you'll stumble on it eventually.  To increase his chances, he names it something common like `mv`.

If you have added `.` to the beginning of your path, and happen to be in the right directory when you type `mv onefile twofile`... then the local `mv` (`./mv`) gets run instead of the `mv` command we're all used too!  This happens because `.` is in your path, and the local `mv` will be found before the `/usr/bin/mv`.  Suddenly, your user account or the entire machine may be horribly compromised.

(note:  mv might be one of the built-in commands, and immune to this.  Not sure... but the principle is solid)

So, you learn the lesson, and now put `.` at the end of your path, so that all "official" directories will be searched before the local directory.

But the attacker is now on to you!  Instead of the program `mv`, he creates in a program `mc`, which is a common typo for `mv`.  Again, you intend to type `mv onefile twofile`, but make a simple typo to `mc`.  Now all the "official" directories are searched, the program `mc` is not found, and finally it is found in the local directory.  Malicious code is run, and again you lose.

The lesson is that your `PATH` should only cover known-good software, and since your current directory changes frequently, you never know exactly what software is there, and should never run it unless you're very explicit about it with the `./` prefix (eg.  **> ./IMeanToRunThis**)

Comment: This is an excellent description despite the lack of star wars quotes

Comment: +1 .. but one more question ... Hmm.. if someone is able to drop an executable into anything other than their home directory, have they not already compromised the machine?

Comment: Nope... there are frequently many shared directories on a machine, consider such common names as /tmp, /public/ftp/uploads.  And a sys-admin may still end up in a users-home directory from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use `$HOME/bin` as a personal collection point for utilities I wrote but that won't be of use to all users. Otherwise, `/usr/local/bin` is often the right place for locally written programs that *are* of use to all users. In any case, I have verified that the latter place was on my path and added `$HOME/bin` as well.

Unless you really *are* an installer, it is probably not a good idea to go dropping programs into `/bin` or `/usr/bin` despite temptation. That would be the moral equivalent of putting your programs in `C:\Windows` or `C:\Windows\System32`. It is effectively never the correct answer.

Learning more about the PATH environment variable and how the shell searches for programs to run is definitely recommended. Also, as pointed out in another comment, just don't add `.` to your PATH because it will come back to haunt you at some point.

**Edit:** Incidentally, I do a very similar thing on my Windows boxen. I always create a sibling to `C:\Program Files` named `C:\Programs`. In there, I make a folder named `bin` and add that to the system path. I use `C:\programs\bin` much like I use `$HOME/bin` on a *nix box, and put any hand-installed (i.e. no *real* Windows installer was used) programs or stuff ported from *nix that can't tolerate spaces in its path in there in other folders such as `C:\Programs\mingw`, `C:\programs\MSYS`, or `C:\programs\cygwin`.

Any small utilities primarily used from the command prompt usually end up in `C:\programs\bin`, but for anything I'm seriously planning to use on more than one PC I generally create a real Windows installer with [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) and let it get installed in `C:\Program Files`.

Comment: If a program cannot tolerate spaces in it's path, than it is an extremely poorly written program. Unix boxes have had paths with spaces in them far longer than Windows has.

Comment: True, but there has been a strong cultural aversion to actually using spaces in file names. The shell's splitting of its command line on whitespace is part of the problem. Similar issues exist on Windows, but the command prompt has been such a small part of the typical user's experience that white space in names is effectively encouraged. The command prompt quoting problems are no smaller, however.

Answer (score 2):

http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html

e.g.

```
alias progname=/path/to/program/progname
```